# Using "where" in this sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote this sentence (actually, part of it ;)

> Similar problems may arise if a voiceless plosive /p/ is understood as a voiced plosive /b/ then a ‘pour’ becomes a ‘bore’. It is especially the case for the Arabic language **where there is** no sound for /p/.

I used "where" because I used "the case" before it. I hope it doesn't refer to the "Arabic language"?! does my construction convey what I mean?

Actually, I am asking about the reference of "where" in the sentence. Because a language is not a location! then it must refer to the "case". For example probably I couldn't say:

> In Arabic where there is no sound for /p/, a "pour" may be perceived a "bore"

Comment: I don't understand your question. The sentence looks okay. It implies that in the Arabic there is no sound for /p/.

Comment: @CopperKettle The question was about the reference of "where". But as the sentence seems Okey, I have no problem with it.

Comment: Yes, "where" in English is a chameleon.  In diseases where,  in situations where,  in events where, in cases where, in songs where, in languages where...

Comment: I believe **where** does refer to "Arabic language". Next comes **there**, a dummy pronoun used to indicate the non-existence of a sound for /p/ in the language.

Comment: Maybe you meant to ask whether we can also use **in which**: "It is especially the case for the Arabic language **in which** there is no sound for /p/."

Comment: I think "which has no /p/ sound" is better than "where there is no sound for /p/".

Comment: @CopperKettle yes thank you, meanwhile I edited my question, however you almost answered it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are more than one Arabic language, which would change things around a bit.  Unless you are talking about all Arabic langauges, which again would change things as well.

Comment: As kind of hinted at by @Copperkettle, *where* can replace *in which* or other prepositio phrases. Because we can use *in which* in your sentence, *where* is also good.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence sounds completely natural. You have used 'where' correctly.

Yes, it is referring to "the case". It's looking at a logical case or situation abstractly, as a location where you can be. Or, at thinking about that case as a location where your mind is.

Then, it's using the language you would use to describe the properties of a location:

> I went to Germany last month, where they don't drink tap water.
>   I live in Colorado, where people ski a lot.
>   This is not the case in Iowa, where there are no mountains.

To speak less abstractly and more directly, you could say:

> It is especially the case for the Arabic language, in which there is no sound for /p/.

This is less abstract because languages include sounds, so the sounds are *in* the language, but a language is not technically a *place* where things can *be*.