# Could "where" mean "while" at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, sentence-structure

I copied the sentence below from somewhere, I am not sure it is a sentence or part of a paragraph. (I added "Therefore" myself)

> ..... Therefore, **where** we need to work on sound-spelling relationships, we have to make sure second language learners have an accurate perception of the sounds.

The usage of "where" in this sentence was new to me, however I think I understand it! it is something like "As" or "While" or maybe the similar usage in this sentence ?

> Where others have been satisfied, Dowson had higher ambitions!

How do you explain this usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "where" in this sentence](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61453/using-where-in-this-sentence)

Comment: This question seems like it is easier to answer than the possible duplicate question.

Comment: How is this different to your earlier question? In this case, ***where*** doesn't mean ***while*** or ***as*** - it simply means *in the specified cases* (as opposed to *other* cases, which are "elsewhere", not under consideration). Since there's no reason to add the extra word *therefore* (which doesn't affect the thing you're asking about) you shouldn't do so - it just adds irrelevant complexity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry I can't see a relation with that question! Here, "where" is at the beginning of the sentence and doesn't look like a relative clause!

Comment: I think it *is* a "relative clause"! Including *therefore* simply complicates the example, but it's essentially *We have to do [blah blah] **where** [blah blah]*, with the "default" clause sequence adjusted.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh! interesting! you mean it means, "in the cases where ...", if it is the case, then the question is still useful! why they should be ommitted, Anyway, that structure was very new and ambiguous to me

Comment: I'm sorry, but I feel you're just making things worse! I'm now totally confused about what's going on here. Instead of copy/pasting the "original", why not ***provide a link**?* I'm currently unsure whether the original text had ***while*** or ***where***, but it completely changes the meaning of the text, so I don't see what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Those two questions are similar, in that 'where' is indicating a case or situation, but the way in which the word is used is different enough that I'm not voting to close.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unfortunately I couldn't find the original sentence, and that is my own paragraph, I used "while" to fit the sentence in my paragraph as I think "where" is not suitable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To show that there are probably other usage of "where" I brought another example, however it might be different from my first sentence usage of "where"

Comment: Well, I voted to close on the grounds that superficially the question doesn't seem to be significantly different to your previous one. If what you *really* need to know is *What difference does it make whether this sentence uses **where** or **while**?* I would gladly cancel my closevote, reverse my downvote to an **upvote**, and answer it.

Comment: [DONE!](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/61476/126)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying the sentence so we can concentrate on what really matters here...

> 1: ***While*** we need to [do one thing], we have to [do some other thing].
>   2: ***Where*** we need to [do one thing], we have to [do some other thing].

In a *very* contrived context<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> they could mean the same, but it's so unlikely you can probably ignore that possibility. Note that ***while*** has these two relatively distinct usages...

> 3: ***While*** breastfeeding, you should eat two to three servings of protein each day.
>    4: ***While*** I agree Greece has borrowed unwisely, I think bankers are the real villains here.

In principle you could replace ***while*** in both cases with the "literal" meaning ***at the same time as***. But by "figurative, idiomatic" extension, in #3 it actually means ***when*** [but not necessarily at other times] and in #4 it means ***although*** [the first thing is true, at the same time, so is the second].

Applying that distinction to OP's example (still slightly simplified), we see that...

> 5: ***While*** we need to work on X, we have to make sure Y [happens].
>    6: ***Where*** we need to work on X, we have to make sure Y [happens].

The default interpretation for #5 is ***Although*** we must work on X, we must **also** ensure Y. The *only* interpretation of #6 is ***In those situations where*** we need to work on X, we must **also** ensure Y.

---

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> (If you've understood the above text this is probably redundant.) Note that "needing to work on X" isn't normally a situation you might be in *periodically* (usually you either need to work on it or you don't - the requirement doesn't keep changing). Using ***while*** X to mean *when X, at the same time as X* always implies that there are other times when X doesn't apply. In OP's context, it's unlikely the writer is drawing a contrast with ***other*** times when we **don't** need to work on sound-spelling relationships.

Comment: Thank you, in summary, I think I should interpret "where" as "In situations where" in such cases. However, based on your final comment in the answer, I think its meaning is close to "Whenever".

Comment: @Ahmad: Since *all* these words *(while, where, when, whenever, although, etc.)* can have different non-overlapping meanings and usages in different contexts, I'm not sure it's necessarily helpful to identify any given pair as "synonymous". It's just that *in certain contexts* some can be replaced by others with no significant change in meaning. In many contexts of the general form #1, #3, #5 above, the meaning of ***while*** can be adequately conveyed by just ***if***.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Therefore" is probably unnecessary.  "Therefore" means "given these facts", which is similar to "in this situation".  As I explain below, this is redundant with "where" in this context.

"Where" in this context is short for "In situations where".

This usage makes me think of geographical and historical analogies.  For example, imagine a country with mountains in the west, and a seacoast in the east.  I could say, "Where the ground slopes from west to east, the rivers tend to run from west to east."

Comment: We have absolutely no idea whether *therefore* is "necessary" (or even *meaningful*), since it depends entirely on unstated preceding context. Which would have to at least *justify* the cited statement in order to make sense, but that wouldn't *force* the word to be included.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I brought the context in my update of the question

Comment: Thank you, is it true about my second example  in the revised question too?

Comment: The "Dowson" sentence is not a very helpful example.  The "Dowson" sentence has not-quite parallel verb tenses in the two clauses.  This makes it harder to explain what the word "Where" means in the example.

Comment: Oh! Actually I borrowed it from Longman dictionary, I was suspected that my sentence is similar to this usage. Longman says: "*It is used to say that one person, thing, opinion etc. is different from another*"

Comment: Overall, apart from this last usage, I think tonight I confused the common usage of "where" as a short for " in situations where", "in places where". it's better go to sleep.